# When to use nested routes in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Hi guys I hope you are doing well
I've been learning react lately, now I'm learning React Router 6 from their documentation and I came across nested routes. I perfectely understood how to implement them but what I didnt grasp is:
When to use nested routes in a react app?
please can someone explain to me this

Comment: I use it to share the navbar between routes. sometimes I wrap the / route with isAuth component to check if user has access to nested routes.

Comment: From https://www.robinwieruch.de/react-router-nested-routes/#:~:text=Nested%20Routes%20are,tab%20gets%20replaced.: Nested Routes are a powerful feature. While most people think React Router only routes a user from page to page, it also allows one to exchange specific fragments of the view based on the current route. For example, on a user page one gets presented multiple tabs (e.g. Profile, Account) to navigate through a user's information. By clicking these tabs, the URL in the browser will change, but instead of replacing the whole page, only the content of the tab gets replaced.

Comment: @NicholasObert if I understood very well 
nested routes are used when you have several pages which almost have the same layout
is that right?

Comment: Yes, that is one use of nested routes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you are asking why one would use nested routes versus a flat list of routes with each path explicitly fully "quantified". Nesting routes mostly serves to make laying out the routes and UI a bit more intuitive.

Flat list of fully "quantified" routes:

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/a" element={<A />} />
  <Route path="/a/b" element={<AB />} />
  <Route path="/a/b/c" element={<ABC />} />
  <Route path="/a/d" element={<AD />} />
  <Route path="/a/d/e" element={<ADE />} />
  <Route path="/a/d/f" element={<ADF />} />
</Routes>
```

vs

Nesting routes

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/a">
    <Route index element={<A />} />        // "/a"
    <Route path="b">
      <Route index element={<AB />} />     // "/a/b"
      <Route path="c" element={<ABC />} /> // "/a/b/c"
    </Route>
    <Route path="d">
      <Route index element={<AD />} />     // "/a/d"
      <Route path="e" element={<ADE />} /> // "/a/d/e"
      <Route path="f" element={<ADF />} /> // "/a/d/f"
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Now it may look like more effort & code is needed for the route nesting (*it is a little bit*), but now if we wanted to change one path segment, say `"/a/d"` to `"/a/g"` you'd only need to change it in one route (*and OFC any links linking to routes*).

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/a">
    <Route index element={<A />} />        // "/a"
    <Route path="b">
      <Route index element={<AB />} />     // "/a/b"
      <Route path="c" element={<ABC />} /> // "/a/b/c"
    </Route>
    <Route path="g"> // <-- only change segment here, nested routes inherit path
      <Route index element={<AD />} />     // "/a/g"
      <Route path="e" element={<ADE />} /> // "/a/g/e"
      <Route path="f" element={<ADF />} /> // "/a/g/f"
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

Nesting routes is also a more natural and intuitive way to compose/layout UI via [layout routes](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/getting-started/concepts#layout-routes) and the [`Outlet`](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/components/outlet) component.

For example, if you wanted a page layout to include a header and footer component on only certain routes:

```
import { Outlet } from 'react-router-dom';

const PageLayout = () => (
  <div className="page">
    <Header />
    <Outlet />
    <Footer />
  </div>
);
```

...

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/a">
    <Route index element={<A />} />
    <Route path="b" element={<PageLayout />}> // only B pages get header/footer
      <Route index element={<AB />} />
      <Route path="c" element={<ABC />} />
    </Route>
    <Route path="d">
      <Route index element={<AD />} />
      <Route path="e" element={<ADE />} />
      <Route path="f" element={<ADF />} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
</Routes>
```

*same with flat list of routes, but now nesting the B pages*

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/a" element={<A />} />
  <Route element={<PageLayout />}>
    <Route path="/a/b" element={<AB />} />
    <Route path="/a/b/c" element={<ABC />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="/a/d" element={<AD />} />
  <Route path="/a/d/e" element={<ADE />} />
  <Route path="/a/d/f" element={<ADF />} />
</Routes>
```

As you see, the same UI can be achieved with and without nesting routes, though some UI designs become ***much*** easier to achieve when nesting routes. This is likely more to do with using layout routes (*as a feature*) than it does using nested routes (*as a feature*), it's difficult to discuss one without the other. In other words, it's the layout routes that are the powerful feature, nesting routes is how they are implemented.

Use route nesting when you want to:

- Use layout routes to share common UI, authentication logic, etc.
- Make it easy to move groups of routes around to other sub-directories